# Edit functionality not works Php MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, deprecated

This is the code for `edit.php` where when I click edit this page opens and edits that specific line.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<?php
/*
  EDIT.PHP
  Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/
// creates the edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email,$job_title,$workplace,$country,$nationality, $error){
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit Entries</title>
    </head>
    <body><?php // if there are any errors, display them
        if ($error != ''){echo '
        <div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
        }
    ?>
        <div class="maindiv">
            <?php include("includes/head.php");?>
            <?php include("menu.php");?>
            <div class="form_div">
                <div class="title"><h2>Updating Report for ID: <?php echo $id;?></p></h2> </div>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\insert.css" type="text/css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\navcss.css" type="text/css" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                    <label>Name:</label><b><label style="margin-left:24em">الاسم</b></label><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Telephone Number:</label><b><label style="margin-left:15em">رقم الهاتف</b><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="telephone_number" value="<?php echo $telephone_number; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Email:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:20em">البريد الإلكتروني</b></label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Job Title:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:19em">المسمى الوظيفي</b></label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="job_title" value="<?php echo $job_title; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Work Place:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:19em">جهه العمل</b></label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="workplace" value="<?php echo $workplace; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Country:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:23em">الدولة</b></label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" /><br />
                    <label>Nationality:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:21em">الجنسية</b></label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="nationality" value="<?php echo $nationality; ?>" /><br />
                    <p>* Required</p>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Record" />
                    <button class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="history.back();return false;">Return to previous page</button>
                 </form>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php } // connect to the database
    include('connect.php');// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])){// get form data, making sure it is valid
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
            $telephone_number = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['telephone_number']));
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
            $job_title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['job_title']));
            $workplace = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['workplace']));
            $country = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['country']));
            $nationality = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nationality']));// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
            if ($name == ''){// generate error message
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';//error, display form
                renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email, $job_title, $workplace, $country, $nationality, $error);
            }
            else{// save the data to the database
                $link->query("UPDATE conf SET name='$name', telephone_number='$telephone_number',email='$email',job_title='$job_title',workplace='$workplace',country='$country',nationality='$nationality' WHERE id=$id");// once saved, redirect back to the view page
                header("Location: view.php");
            }
        }
        else{// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
            echo 'Error!';
        }
    }
    else{ // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
        // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0){// query db
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM conf WHERE id=$id");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
            if($row){// get data from db
                $name=$row['name'];
                $telephone_number = $row['telephone_number'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $job_title = $row['job_title'];
                $workplace = $row['workplace'];
                $country = $row['country'];
                $nationality = $row['nationality'];// show form //renderForm($id, $first_name,$emp_number,$department,$email, '');
                renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email,$job_title,$workplace,$country,$nationality, '');
            }
            else{// if no match, display result
                echo "No results!";
            }
        }
        else{// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
            echo 'Error!';
        }
    }
?>
```

It gives first warning that mysql is deprecated so I used below syntax but still it gives error:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($link,$_POST['name']));
```

Second major error its giving is that it takes me to this error message and makes all form fields empty. The line its showing always is:

> ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!

Please Guide!

Comment: `$link` should be the first argument to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, not to `htmlspecialchars()`. There's also no good reason to call `htmlspecialchars()` at all when storing data in the database. It should only be used when displaying data on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $servername = "localhost:3306";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "<Password here>";
        $dbname = "TUTORIALS";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tutorials_inf(name)VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
           echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        $conn->close();
     }
```

Comment: Whats this dear @bmodanwal I asked for edit not create

Answer (score 0):

```
$link->query($conn,"UPDATE conf SET name='$name', telephone_number='$telephone_number',email='$email',job_title='$job_title',workplace='$workplace',country='$country',nationality='$nationality' WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: same error .. ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!

Answer (score 0):

I Solved My-Self...

Code Below...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<?php

/*

EDIT.PHP

Allows user to edit specific entry in database

*/



// creates the edit record form

// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

function renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email,$job_title,$workplace,$country,$nationality, $error)

{

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Edit Entries</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php

// if there are any errors, display them

if ($error != '')

{

echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

}

?>

<div class="maindiv">
<?php include("includes/head.php");?>
<?php include("menu.php");?>
        <!--HTML form -->
            <div class="form_div">
            <div class="title"><h2>Updating Report for ID: <?php echo $id;?></p></h2> </div>
<form action="" method="post">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\insert.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\navcss.css" type="text/css" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

                    <label>Name:</label><b><label style="margin-left:24em">الاسم</b></label>
                    <br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Telephone Number:</label><b><label style="margin-left:15em">رقم الهاتف</b>
                    <br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="telephone_number" value="<?php echo $telephone_number; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Email:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:20em">البريد الإلكتروني</b></label>       
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Job Title:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:19em">المسمى الوظيفي</b></label>       
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="job_title" value="<?php echo $job_title; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Work Place:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:19em">جهه العمل</b></label>       
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="workplace" value="<?php echo $workplace; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Country:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:23em">الدولة</b></label>       
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Nationality:</label></label><b><label style="margin-left:21em">الجنسية</b></label>       
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="nationality" value="<?php echo $nationality; ?>" />
                    <br />
<p>* Required</p>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Record" />
<button class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="history.back(); return false;">Return to previous page</button>


</form>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>

<?php

}

// connect to the database

$mysqli = new mysqli("sql213.byethost7.com", "b7_21234466", "mazhar2012", "b7_21234466_conference");



// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid


$id = $_POST['id'];

$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

//$name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));

//$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name']));

$telephone_number = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['telephone_number']);

$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$job_title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['job_title']);

$workplace = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['workplace']);

$country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

$nationality = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nationality']);


// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in

if ($name == '')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

//error, display form


renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email, $job_title, $workplace, $country, $nationality, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

$mysqli->query("UPDATE conf SET name='$name', telephone_number='$telephone_number',email='$email',job_title='$job_title',workplace='$workplace',country='$country',nationality='$nationality' WHERE id=$id");



// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: view.php");

}

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

echo 'Error!';

}

}

else

// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form

{


// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

{

// query db

$id = $_GET['id'];


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM conf WHERE id=$id");



$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);



// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse

if($row)

{

// get data from db

        $name=$row['name'];
        $telephone_number = $row['telephone_number'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $job_title = $row['job_title'];
        $workplace = $row['workplace'];
        $country = $row['country'];
        $nationality = $row['nationality'];


// show form

//renderForm($id, $first_name,$emp_number,$department,$email, '');
renderForm($id, $name, $telephone_number, $email,$job_title,$workplace,$country,$nationality, '');

}

else

// if no match, display result

{

echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}

}

?>
```